# Capitalizing within a sentence

Tags: capitalization

I am writing dialogue. I have googled this to no avail.

> Jane said, "What is your vision statement?"
> Mike replied, "It's 'To make men of men.'"

Should "To" be capitalized, and are the single quotes correct?

Answer (score 0):

In contemporary fiction, dialogue is commonly written "as you hear it". For example, you cannot say or hear a numerical digit ("I bought 5 eggs."), what you say and hear is the word for that number ("I bought five eggs."), therefore you use the word ("five") when you write dialogue.

Using this rule it immediately becomes apparent that you can neither hear capitalisation nor quotation marks in spoken language. Your example would therefore commonly be rendered as:

> Jane said, "What is your vision statement?"
> Mike replied, "It's to make men of men."

What you can use in written representation of spoken language is emphasis, e.g. "to make *men* of men". So if Mike spoke the phrase "to make men of men" in a pathetic, declamatory voice, you could write:

> Mike struck a pose and said: "It's *to make men of men*."

In this case there would probably be a brief pause after "it's" and you could capitalize the phrase if you indicated that pause:

> Mike struck a pose and said: "It is: *To make men of men.*"

There is [some disagreement](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/19318/using-colons-and-semi-colons-in-dialogue) whether colons and semicolons can be used in dialogue. Usually, in dialogue, you use commas and dashes to signify pauses. Colons and semicolons are exceedingly rare in dialogue and I personally wouldn't use them. I would solve that problem by inserting narrative where the pause is in the speech:

> "It is," Mike struck a pose, "*To make men of men.*"

Sometimes people use gestures to mimic quotation marks with their fingers, but this doesn't have the meaning of indicating a citation. Instead the meaning of that gesture is ironic or sarcastic, signalling that the speaker disagrees with a certain application of the term (e.g. "These so-called" – Mike made a quoting gesture – "managers. All they *manage* is to intefere with our work.").

There are some few exceptions to the rule to write spoken language as we hear it. One example is the capitalisation of names. In *The Lord of the Rings*, Sauron's ring is called "the One Ring". Since this is a name, it is capitalized, and like any other name (e.g. Frodo) it is capitalized in dialogue as well, despite the fact that we cannot hear capitalization of names:

> "Please, Frodo, give me the One Ring," Bilbo begged.   ← *correct*
> <strike>"Please, frodo, give me the one ring," Bilbo begged.</strike>   ← *wrong*